# Database file information not saved when downloaded back from Heroku to my PC

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I am doing a Discord.py bot and my bot needs a database to store guilds, members and stuff. I uploaded my files (a created database file too) with git to Heroku and ran my bot. When people join Discord server or something, it has to record that to the database.
When I downloaded all my files back from Heroku to my computer with `heroku git:clone -a <name>` I see that my database is still empty, even though a member has joined. When I run my bot on my computer directly, database works fine. Why? Does Heroku even update files when my code says so? Maybe I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Maybe I misunderstood something?

Yes. You deploy code to heroku by pushing it to its git repo. That's when your blank/default database file is. When heroku starts a dyno, it essentially copies the files from the git repo into the filesystem on the new dyno. As your app works, it can read and write the files on the dyno. The important points are:

1. Writes to that dyno-local file are not propagated back to git.
2. The dyno filesystem is **ephemeral**. When your dyno shuts down, the files are gone and all the changes are gone with them.

If you want a persisted database that can survive dyno restarts, you should use an external database instead of a local file. For example, a Postgres add-on.

Comment: Is there a way to download files back from a DYNO you mentioned? P.S. - Sorry for late (I wasn't on PC for a long time...)

Comment: @M3ther: you can try this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#copying-files-from-a-dyno

Comment: Oh, thanks, Sergio. But I think I'll just need to learn and use PostgreSQL for the database and put my bot to heroku :)

Comment: @M3ther yes, that is the way to go.